# Golang gorilla parse date with specific format from form

Tags: go, gorilla

I receive date from form. This date has specific format "dd/mm/yyyy".

For parsing it to my struct I use gorilla/schema package, but this package can't recognize received data as date.

How I can parse date and put it in struct right way? As field it has format "01/02/2006"

My implementation:

```
type User struct {
  Date   time.Time `schema:"date"`
}


func MyRoute(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  user := User{}
  r.ParseForm()
  defer r.Body.Close()

  decoder := schema.NewDecoder()
  if err := decoder.Decode(&user, r.Form); err != nil {
     fmt.Println(err)
  }
  .......................
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this answer because I don't have time to build up an example, but according to this: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema

> The supported field types in the destination struct are:
>
> - bool
> - float variants (float32, float64)
> - int variants (int, int8, int16, int32, int64)
> - string
> - uint variants (uint, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64)
> - struct
> - a pointer to one of the above types
> - a slice or a pointer to a slice of one of the above types
>
> Non-supported types are simply ignored, however custom types can be 
>   registered to be converted.

so you need to say:

```
var timeConverter = func(value string) reflect.Value {
    if v, err := time.Parse("02/01/2006", value); err == nil {
        return reflect.ValueOf(v)
    }
    return reflect.Value{} // this is the same as the private const invalidType
}

func MyRoute(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user := User{}
    r.ParseForm()
    defer r.Body.Close()
    decoder := schema.NewDecoder()
    decoder.RegisterConverter(time.Time{}, timeConverter)

    if err := decoder.Decode(&user, r.Form); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

see: https://github.com/gorilla/schema/blob/master/decoder.go

Comment: thx, it works! Just format should be `"02/01/2006"` for `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: great! I fixed the date fmt in the answer.